# Downloading a torrent file with WebClient, results in corrupt file

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I'm trying to download a .torrent file (not the contents of the torrent itself) in my .NET application.

Using the following code works for other files, but not .torrent. The resulting files is about 1-3kb smaller than if I download the file via a browser. When opening it in a torrent client, it says the torrent is corrupt.

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
web.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-bittorrent");
web.DownloadFile("http://kat.ph/torrents/linux-mint-12-gnome-mate-dvd-64-bit-t6008958/", "test.torrent");
```

Opening the URL in a browser results in the file being downloaded correctly.

Any ideas as to why this would happen? Are there any good alternatives to WebClient that would download the file correctly?

EDIT: I've tried this as well as WebClient, and it results in the same thing:

```
private void DownloadFile(string url, string file)
    {
        byte[] result;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(url);
        wr.ContentType = "application/x-bittorrent";
        using (WebResponse response = wr.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);

                    } while (count != 0);

                    result = memoryStream.ToArray();

                    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create)))
                    {
                        writer.Write(result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: HttpWebRequest gives you more control over your download ... I'm not sure what options you'd need to configure for a torrent though.

Comment: Thanks! I had actually tried that as well, with no difference in results. I've edited that code in. If you see anything I did wrong in trying that let me know.

Comment: Shouldn't be any difference in downloading a .torrent file than downloading any other binary file.

Comment: I agree there shouldn't be. The problem is that there seems to be, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. Just from basic HTTP I wonder why are you setting the `Content-Type`? Isn't that a header used by the server? Maybe it should be the `Accept` header?

Comment: It was suggested to someone else for a somewhat similar problem I found on a forum. It didn't solve the problem. I tried it with the Accept header instead, but no change. Thanks though.

Comment: Attach the example of URL to download

Comment: Edited the original post with an example URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem that server returns content compressed by **gzip** and you download this compressed content to file. For such cases you should check the "Content-Encoding" header and use proper stream reader to decompress the source.
I modified your function to handle gzipped content:

```
private void DownloadFile(string url, string file)
    {
        byte[] result;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(url);
        wr.ContentType = "application/x-bittorrent";
        using (WebResponse response = wr.GetResponse())
        {
            bool gzip = response.Headers["Content-Encoding"] == "gzip";
            var responseStream = gzip
                                    ? new GZipStream(response.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress)
                                    : response.GetResponseStream();

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int count = 0;
                do
                {
                    count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                } while (count != 0);

                result = memoryStream.ToArray();

                using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    writer.Write(result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Should have thought of compression!

Comment: I seem to have a similar problem. I'm using python (urllib2.urlopen)...how do I check encoding and unzip the file in python? thanks