# Download a torrent file result is corrupt WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

in an app I am making some of the files required are torrent files but i'm having an odd issue, whenever I download a torrent file through the app the files ends up corrupt and wont open in any torrent app, I used wptools to extract them to a pc and test it and still corrupt here is my code I can't see what 'im doing wrong, I am fairly new to using webclient. I assume it has something to do with the way im saving the file any help would be great thanks.

```
   private void tbLink_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {  
        string[] linkInfo = (sender as TextBlock).Tag as string[];
        fileurl = linkInfo[0];
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fileurl);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.OpenReadCompleted += client_OpenReadCompleted;
        client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(fileurl), linkInfo);
        client.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;             
    }

    async void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] linkInfo = e.UserState as string[];
        filetitle = linkInfo[1];
        filesave = (filetitle);               
        var isolatedfile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();           
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = isolatedfile.OpenFile(filesave, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
            while (e.Result.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }
        try
        {
            StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile torrentfile = await local.GetFileAsync(filesave);
            Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(torrentfile);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File Not Found");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
while (e.Result.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
{
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

The `Read` method will return the number of bytes read, it can be less than `buffer.Length`. So the code should read:

```
int byteCount;
// Select an appropriate buffer size. 
// This is a buffer, not space for the entire file.
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; 
while ((byteCount = e.Result.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
}
```

**UPDATE**: If the data is compressed, as in the question that you posted in your comment, then you can decompress the stream:

```
int byteCount;
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; 
using (GZipStream zs = new GZipStream(e.Result, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    while ((byteCount = zs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
    }
}
```

Note that I have not tested this code, I'm assuming that `e.Result` is a stream.

Comment: The files Are still corrupt, i've just come across this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857709/downloading-a-torrent-file-with-webclient-results-in-corrupt-file but i don't know how to implicate this

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, your a bloody genius.